# Convergence of Jacobi-Method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $C \in \mathbb R^{n,n}$ be a symmetric, positive-definit matrix and $D_C$ be a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries of C.

Furthermore let $$\bar{C} = 2D_C -C$$ be a positive-definit matrix.

Show that the Jacobi-method converges for $C x=b$.

So let $F^2 = D_C. $

I tried to check the matrix $I_n-F^{-1}CF^{-1}$. Since C is a symmetric positive definit matrix i know that all eigenvalues are positive. I tried to also check the spectral radius but i am really lost here.

Comment: @CarlChristian yes i edited it just now. It is to solve $Cx=b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a more general statement (**Householder-John theorem**):

> Let $A$ and $M+M^*-A$ be Hermitian positive definite and $M$ be an invertible matrix. Then $\rho(I-M^{-1}A)<1$.

Let $\lambda$ and $x\neq 0$ be an eigenvalue and an eigenvector of $I-M^{-1}A$ so
$$
(I-M^{-1}A)x=\lambda x \iff (1-\lambda)Mx=Ax.
$$
We have $\lambda\neq 1$, otherwise $A$ would be singular.
Premultiplying by $x^*$ and taking a conjugate transpose gives
$$
x^*Mx=\frac{1}{1-\lambda}x^*Ax, \quad
x^*M^*x=\frac{1}{1-\bar{\lambda}}x^*Ax.
$$
Hence
$$
x^*(M+M^*-A)x=\left(\frac{1}{1-\lambda}+\frac{1}{1-\bar{\lambda}}-1\right)x^*Ax
=\frac{1-|\lambda|^2}{|1-\lambda|^2}x^*Ax.
$$
Both $A$ and $M+M^*-A$ are HPD, we have $x^*(M+M^*-A)x>0$ and $x^*Ax>0$. 
Therefore
$$
1-|\lambda|^2>0\iff |\lambda|<1.
$$

---

Now to answer the question, set $A:=C$ and $M:=D_C$ to get:

> If $C$ and $2D_C-C$ are positive definite then $\rho(I-D_C^{-1}C)<1$ and the Jacobi method for $Cx=b$ is convergent.

Comment: Ahh i understand. Thank you alot